# How do I use AbortController when the user clicks a button and then navigates away?

Tags: react-native, abortcontroller

I'm fairly new to `AbortController` and so far I've only used it in `useEffect` callbacks.  However, I have a screen in my React Native app which allows the user to click a button to open a dialog; in the background the button click causes an `axios` call to the api, and then the retrieved information is shown in the dialog.

But what happens if the user clicks the button and then quickly navigates away?  In this case, the information doesn't need to be retrieved, and it can't be displayed once it's been retrieved anyway.

Is there a way to handle this? ie can I set up an `AbortController` and then if the user navigates away from the screen, abort the signal so that the api call gets cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I understand you correctly, but you can use useEffect cleanup function to cancel axios request. About cleanup function: https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm.

If you want you can prevent user to go back, until axios fetching is done-> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The situation I have is that it's NOT in a useEffect.  So the axios request is triggered by the user clicking a button to see more information on something.  If the user then navigates away from the page, the request is no longer needed.  Is there a way to tell the request that it's no longer needed?